# Multiple SerialPort returns in real-time

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have made a data logging application in C#. It connects to 4 USB sensors with the SerialPort class. I have the data received event threshold triggered on every byte. When data is received, the program checks to see if that byte is the end of the line. If it isn't, the input is added to a buffer. If it is a line end, the program adds a timestamp and writes the data and timestamp to a file (each input source gets a dedicated file).

Issues arise when using more than one COM port inputs. What I see in the output files is:

Any of the 4 Files:

```
...
timestamp1 value1
timestamp2 value2
timestamp3 value3
value4
value5
value6
timestamp7 value7
...
```

So, what it looks like is the computer isn't fast enough to get to all 4 interrupts before the next values arrive. I have good reason to believe that this is the culprit because sometimes I'll see output like this:

```
...
timestamp value
timestamp value
value
val
timestamp ue
timestamp value
...
```

It might be due to the fact that I changed the processor affinity to run only on Core 2. I did this because the timestamps I'm using are counted with processor cycles, so I can't have multiple time references depending on which core is running. I've put some of the code snippets below; any suggestions that might help with the dropped timestamps would be greatly appreciated!

```
    public mainLoggerIO()
    {
        //bind to one cpu
        Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        long AffinityMask = (long)proc.ProcessorAffinity;
        AffinityMask &= 0x0002; //use only the 2nd processor
        proc.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)AffinityMask;

        //prevent any other threads from using core 2
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

        long frequency = Stopwatch.Frequency;
        Console.WriteLine("  Timer frequency in ticks per second = {0}",
            frequency);
        long nanosecPerTick = (1000L * 1000L * 1000L) / frequency;
        Console.WriteLine("  Timer is accurate within {0} nanoseconds",
            nanosecPerTick);

        if (Stopwatch.IsHighResolution)
            MessageBox.Show("High Resolution Timer Available");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No High Resolution Timer Available on this Machine");

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And so on. Each data return interrupt looks like this:

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //serialPort1.DataReceived = serialPort1_DataReceived;
        rawPort1Data = "";
        rawPort1Data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { returnTextPort1(); });
    }
```

The method returnTextPort#() is:

```
    private void returnTextPort1()
    {
        if (string.Compare(saveFileName, "") == 0)//no savefile specified
            return;
        bufferedString += rawPort1Data;
        if(bufferedString.Contains('\r')){
            long timeStamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            textBox2.AppendText(nicknames[0] + " " + timeStamp / 10000 + ", " + rawPort1Data);
            //write to file
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@saveFileName, true))
            {
                 file.WriteLine(nicknames[0] + " " + timeStamp / 10000 + ", " + rawPort1Data);//in Ms
            }
            bufferedString = "";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please pay close attention to the terminology you're using. COM in programming is something entirely different than the serial port.

Comment: This is true - I meant COM as it refers to serial communications.

Comment: I have yet to see a serial port that operates in the Ghz range so I doubt your PC is slower than the input. It's more likely that all of your events are being triggered on the same thread (the main thread) which would most result in discernible events which would appear as data bleed. Have you considered offloading the processing to different threads or even child processes to enforce separation between your COM activity?

Comment: I could try that. If I did spin off a thread for each receive event, would they still be tied to Core 2 via the processor affinity statement?

Comment: I think a problem is that your `returnTextPort1()` is doing far too much - I'd move the log file update to a separate thread, and cache `new System.IO.StreamWriter` as that's not going to be a cheap operation. Furthermore, by moving to a separate thread you can implement mutexes to prevent the interleaved output you mention.

Comment: With using different threads for each return, how could I go about being sure that two threads don't get hold of the same file at the same time?

Comment: I strongly recommend you completely forget about core affinity and high-resolution timers for this application. We're talking about serial ports and the Win32 message pump.

Comment: Is that to say that the resolutions of the serial ports and message pump are so low that the timers don't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner approach would be to use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` between the data received event handler and a separate Thread that will deal with the resulting data.  That way the event handler can return immediately AND instead of modifying `rawPort1` data in a totally non-thread-safe manner you could move to a thread-safe solution.

Create a Thread that reads from the concurrent queue, writes to the file and Invokes the UI changes.  Note that writing to the file should NOT be on the UI thread.

Your `ConcurrentQueue<T>` can capture in the class `T` that you will implement: the port number, the data received and the timestamp at which it was received.

Note also that `DateTime.Now` is rarely ever the right answer, for most locations it jumps by an hour twice every year when daylight savings time starts or ends, instead of `DateTime.UtcNow`.  Note however that neither has the accuracy you seem to be trying to obtain with your `StopWatch` code.

You should not need to manipulate processes or thread priorities to do this: the serial port has a buffer, you'll not miss data provided you handle it efficiently.

Comment: +1 Good answer but only applicable depending on the OP's meaning of "real time" and the volume of data he's dealing with.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions! I will try that out. For the timestamps, I never was able to find a very good answer online about what was best to use. I'm trying to get as precise a timing as possible with respect to the first received stamp. Do you happen to know what's best for this, and how good it can be?

Comment: The four sources send data at 10, 3, 3, and 6 Hz, respectively. Logging will need to continue for 2-3 hours.

Comment: Use `StopWatch` rather than `DateTime.UtcNow`.  Given that you are receiving strings over a serial port you already have a fairly long duration just for the message to be transmitted; you shouldn't need anything more accurate.

Comment: You might want to also accumulate the line in the event handler and only push it to the queue when you hit the return character.  Simply changing that in your current solution would clean things up quite a bit and you could pass the line through to the Invoked method rather than letting it read from the variable in an unsafe manner.